# Carousel item only visible while sliding

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I’m working on a bootstrap website and trying to implement a carousel. But for some weird reason the slides are only visible while they are coming in the screen.

I tried using the bootstrap code on https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/carousel/ but I get the same result. I feel like I’ve tried everything there is so I the only thing I can think of is that the problem is in the bootstrap files. I included the html down below and could share the bootstrap files to if needed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>carousel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-grid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-grid.css.map">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-grid.rtl.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-grid.rtl.css.map">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-grid.rtl.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-grid.rtl.min.css.map">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-reboot.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-reboot.css.map">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css.map">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-reboot.rtl.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-reboot.rtl.css.map">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-reboot.rtl.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-reboot.rtl.min.css.map">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-utilities.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-utilities.css.map">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-utilities.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-utilities.min.css.map">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-utilities.rtl.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-utilities.rtl.css.map">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-utilities.rtl.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-utilities.rtl.min.css.map">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css.map">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css.map">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.rtl.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.rtl.css.map">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css.map">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-indicators">
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="0" class=""
                aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"
                class="active" aria-current="true"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"
                class=""></button>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg d-block w-100" width="800" height="400"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: First slide"
                    preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false">
                    <title>Placeholder</title>
                    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#555"
                        dy=".3em">First slide</text>
                </svg>
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h5>First slide label</h5>
                    <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg d-block w-100" width="800" height="400"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Second slide"
                    preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false">
                    <title>Placeholder</title>
                    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#666"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#444"
                        dy=".3em">Second slide</text>
                </svg>
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h5>Second slide label</h5>
                    <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg d-block w-100" width="800" height="400"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Third slide"
                    preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false">
                    <title>Placeholder</title>
                    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#555"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#333"
                        dy=".3em">Third slide</text>
                </svg>
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h5>Third slide label</h5>
                    <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions"
            data-bs-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions"
            data-bs-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    </div>


    <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.js.map"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js.map"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.esm.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.esm.js.map"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.esm.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.esm.min.js.map"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js.map"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js.map"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[picture of what i see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rC8pL.png)

Comment: Why do you have all those bootstrap stylesheets separately? Maybe start by getting rid of all of those?

Comment: because it isn't the whole website. it's just a part of it and need them

Comment: What I mean is that you are including multiple times the same thing. If you include bootstrap.css you have everything already. Take a look [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/contents/#css-files)

Comment: ahhh oke, it's my first time working with bootstrap. And my boss at my intership told me to include them all. so that's what i did

Comment: Try to change that to the right way and see if that makes a difference. Then create a snippet here so we can see things in action.

Comment: removing all but main bootstrap file link did fix the problem so thans sven

Comment: couldn't get the code snippet to work but this https://codepen.io/drdevil27/pen/KKymQdx should work

Comment: Glad to hear it's fixed! :)